# skip N elements in loop whenever condition is met

Tags: scala

Is there a straightforward idiomatic way, maybe even existing method to accomplish this in scala:

Perform a loop/iterator checking every element in a sequence against a condition. Whenever the condition is met, skip the next N elements, then continue checking the rest until condition is met again, skip N elements and so on.

The only way I thought of is to use a mutable counter or a tail recursion. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I personally would go with a tail-recursion, but you may reduce the boilerplate using a `foldLeft`

Comment: use a mutable counter.

Comment: [Here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/GHYzeEaaTZeb26XdQaUBXA/10) are a couple of alternatives using `tailrec`, `foldLeft` and the `State` monad from **cats**. In this case, I would go with `foldLeft` since is the clearest of the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive routine is the right way to go, something like this:

```
def filterSkip[T](list: List[T], f: T => Boolean, skip: Int): List[T] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(l: List[T], res: List[T]): List[T] =
    l match {
      case Nil => res.reverse
      case hd::tail =>
        if (f(hd)) {
          loop(tail.drop(skip), res)
        } else {
          loop(tail, hd +: res)
        }
    }

  loop(list, Nil)
}
```

This version drops the matching element and N following elements, but it could be easily modified to retain the matching element if required.

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned `unfold()` (Scala 2.13.x).

```
def select[A](input: List[A], test: A=>Boolean, skipN: Int): List[A] =
  List.unfold(input){ lst =>
    Option.when(lst.nonEmpty){
      if (test(lst.head)) (lst.head, lst.tail.drop(skipN))
      else (lst.head, lst.tail)
    }
  }
```

In this version, every element that is tested for "a condition" is an element of the result, the skipped elements are (of course) not.